# How to run mulitple laravel apps locally using xampp and make them accessible to other PCs on my local network

Tags: laravel, windows, xampp, laravel-8, virtualhost

Hi I am on windows and I am using xampp and Laravel

I have multiple laravel apps and I want to run them at the same time and make them accessible to other PC on my local network.

Is it possible ? if yes, how ?

I want also, if possible, to run these apps without php artisan serve command.

I did it for one app using the httpd-vhosts.conf of xampp but didn't know how to do it for multiple apps.
So what I did is I created a virtual host to  make one app accessible directly from another PC through browser using IP address, so is there a way to create multiple virtual hosts like this at the same time ? or there is a better way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to xampp\apache\conf\extra and open httpd-vhosts.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/laravel2/public"
    ServerName laravel2.dev
    <Directory "/Users/laravel2/public">
            AllowOverride All
            Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/laravel1/public"
    ServerName laravel1.dev
    <Directory "/Users/laravel1/public">
            AllowOverride All
            Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Go =>  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1  localhost laravel1.dev
127.0.0.1  localhost laravel2.dev
```

Restart your apache. It's working for me.

Comment: DocumentRoot "/Users/laravel2/public" This path your htdoc should be.

Comment: It does not work for me on windows 10 !! 
BTW what about accessing these apps from other PCs on same local network ?

Comment: can u put picture about. httpd-vhosts.conf file and hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I recommend you to use [Laragon](https://laragon.org/) instead of xampp.

Some of Laragon Features:

- Easy to use.
- Use **app.test** instead of **localhost/app** and no need extra configuration for this.
- No need to run **php artisan serve** command to run laravel project
- You can share your local project with anyone over the internet in just matter of some clicks
- You can move Laragon folder around (to another disks, to another laptops, sync to Cloud,…) without any worries.

Anyway, I'm using [Laragon](https://laragon.org/) all the time.